# ReclaimMe Recovery of the Table used to identify member disk in RAID 5 array

Tags: raid-5

I have seen this issue posted on many forums with only one possible solution (suggested below) and before I attempt I thought the community could weigh in on this solution and then we can share it with others of similar problems!

My ICHR10 raid controller on my Gigabyte x58a-ud3r motherboad is show my 2 "raid 5" arrays (3 drives in each of the 2 array) as non-member.

Short and skinny this was caused by A) CMOS reset, or B) windows install cd launching with no C drive plugged in so it has apparently affect whatever/wherever the data is stored to identify that array000 contains 3 member disk, and array000 contains 3 member disk

I believe I have sucessfully identified which 3 drives go to array000 and which 3 drives go to array001 using software ReclaiMe RAID recovery.  However, now that I have this semi-useful information I dont know what to do next.

My research only turns up that I should set BIOS back to RAID, and this is the scary part, reset ALL disk to non-member disk, then set them up as member disk in their original format (ie same 3 drive in each of the 2 array) and same strip size.

I am wondering if anyone has experience or theories on whether this will restore the (i have no idea what its called, "meta table") whatever is stored to identify that important information.

Or if my reseting them to non-member disk I would screw myself out of being about to worst case use a "recovery" program to recover the data which im sure with 12TB would take a month to do.

Any tips, suggestions are helpful.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you try the recover prior to resetting the disks to non member disks.  This way you have a backup in advance.